# How to factor this expression

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having a little problem factoring this problem.

$$ 
% Commenting out image ![enter image description here][1]
\newcommand{\red}  [1]{\color{red}{#1}}
v(\red 2) = \lim_{t \to \red 2} \frac{\left(\red{47}t - 16t^2\right) - \red{30}}{t - \red 2}$$

so far I have (-16 + ?)(t - ?)

Help as well as strategy welcomed

Comment: this is what happens when you go into calculus without the necessary algebra/arithmetics skills.

Comment: I received a B+ in  College level Algebra; thus, your conclusion is wrong. This is a difficult problem to factor.

Comment: @Cetshwayo The problem is factoring $-16t^2+47-30$. This is supposed to be trivial if you know how to solve a quadratic equation.

Comment: I have been up all day. I just noticed that. Sometimes I get thrown of if the polynomial is not in standard form.

Comment: @Cetshwayo It's all good. It probably has had happen to many people.

Comment: i am sorry if you took my comment personally. the comment was not directed at you but i am seeing this more and more. anyway, one way to go about this is to know the factor theorem for polynomials. that says if $f(a) = 0,$ then $(t-a)$ is a factor. in your example $f(t) = 47t-16t^2 - 30$  and $t = 2.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$47t-16t^2-30=-16t^2+32t+15t-30$

Comment: How did you know to split 47t into 32t and 15t?